# R code ggplot/googlemaps

Tags: r, google-maps, ggplot2

I am trying to get this to work (the links below are all the same thing really) code included at bottom of first link.

Looks like the google maps part doesn't work, does anyone know why?
Also looks like the text overlay doesn't work, also why?

http://workfeed.baileyplex.com/2013/02/maps-in-r-choropleth-maps.html

http://www.r-bloggers.com/maps-in-r-choropleth-maps/

http://www.milanor.net/blog/?p=634

Originally, I couldn't get anything to work but found a post on here about reinstalling several packages and that got me to this point.

Comment: Would you be able to provide your code and the error message you received? Just saying the sample code does not work is unlikely to help others see what is going on.

Comment: The sample code is attached to the 1st post as indicated. There is no error message. The google and text overlays do not work. Here is the link http://www.milanor.net/blog/wp-content/plugins/wp-codebox/wp-codebox.php?p=634&download=maps3.R